# Can I have data from different fields of a model returned as separate HTML elements? (Django 2.1)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am compiling a database of articles and have my model set up like this:

```
class articles(models.Model):
    ArticleID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    Journal = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Date = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Issue = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Link = models.URLField(max_length=800, null=True)
    Content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TEST'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.Title}, {self.Author}, {self.Journal},{self.Date}, {self.Issue}, {self.Content}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', args=[str(self.ArticleID)])
```

The idea is pretty simple. Each meta data type (i.e. title, author) is it's own field, and the actual content of the article is in the field `Content`. 
My view for this model:

```
def article_detail(request, ArticleID):
    ArticleID = get_object_or_404(articles, ArticleID=ArticleID)
    context = {'ArticleID': ArticleID}
    return render(request, 'article_detail.html', context)
```

The HTML template for the view:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container"> 
{{ ArticleID }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The data displayed in on the HTML page is one big block of text in one single HTML element. How can I make it so that I can use CSS to target each individual field from the model? Must I make separate models for each field (and bound them with foreign keys)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No of course not. You can access fields with normal dot notation: `ArticleID.Title`, `ArticleID.Author`, etc.

(But you shouldn't call your context variable `ArticleID`; it's the whole article, not the ID. Also, Python style is to use lower_case_with_underscore for variables and attribute names.)

Comment: Ah, that's so intuitive! =P thanks (will accept as correct answer once the required time passes)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a primary key in for every model which is called `id`, you don't have to explicitly declare that.
Secondly you are getting an article object with `get_object_or_404` so if you use `.` (dot) notation you will get your desired value in your template.
Something like-

```
<h2>{{article.Title}}</h2>
<p>{{article.Content}}</p>
```

though you have to send `article` names instead of ArticleID in context variable.
In addition to Mr. Daniel Roseman's comment you should use class name `Article` instead of `articles` which is not pythonic.